# Scala JS + scalable typed + vite

Tags: vite, scala.js, scalably-typed

I'm stumped by the following error message.

As far as I can tell, scalably typed has successfully processed langchain, and the types appear to be available for use in the IDE. The code compiles and links fine. It's being served through Vite. Here's the error.

```
[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Missing "./dist/agents" specifier in "langchain" package
/Users/simon/Code/mill-full-stack/mill-full-stack/out/frontend/fastLinkJS.dest/frontend.ChatPage$.js
```

I can make the error disappear, by commenting out this line of my code.

```
    val toolkit = OpenApiToolkit(
      JsonSpec(bah),
      baseModel, 
      StringDictionary("Content-Type" -> "application/json", "Authorization" -> apiKey)
    )
```

If I open the offending file, I find this;

```
'use strict';
import * as $i_js$002dyaml from "js-yaml";
import * as $i_langchain$002fdist$002fagents from "langchain/dist/agents";
import * as $i_langchain$002fdist$002ftools$002fjson from "langchain/dist/tools/json";
```

It would appear then, that js-yaml resolved correctly.

For `langchain/dist/agents`, navigate to file works, is tab-completable by VSCode and takes me to this file.
`/Users/simon/Code/mill-full-stack/mill-full-stack/node_modules/langchain/dist/agents/index.d.ts`

I'm a bit stumped, on what the issue is about? Would anyone have a hint on how I could go about tracking this down?